# How do I debug my appengine site being offline?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Coding n00b here - I have a website here which is a python site on appengine:

http://www.7bks.com/

And it's currently down. Completely unavailable. My appengine dashboard appears normal, no quota denials, no errors and when I try and visit there's no log generated (because I can't even reach the site).

I also can't reach the application directly via the appspot URL so it's not an issue with my domain name.

The Appengine status shows everything is groovy:

http://code.google.com/status/appengine/

So what gives? How do I figure out how to get it back online? Not even sure where to start debugging. I've not pushed any code for a few months so everything should be just ticking over?

UPDATE: hey guys, never got to the bottom of why this was happening but I shifted my DNS to the GoogleDNS (http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) and it seems to work fine now so I guess it's solved :)

Comment: I see it do you have a DNS problem? What is the error given by chrome? What answers a traceroute?

Comment: It works for me, are you sure?

Comment: How do I tell if I have a DNS problem? Sorry, coding n00b. Everything else online seems to load fine (including other appengine apps). How do I run a traceroute?

Comment: Check your DNS mapping, www.7bks.com ==> your-app.appspot.com

Answer (score 2):

**Check if you have a DNS problem**

Open the application with Google Chrome and when you get an error you will see the error code with the explanation on the bottom.

**Check if you have a link issue**

In a terminal type

```
traceroute http://www.7bks.com/
```

and see what it gives

Anyway it is more likely to be a DNS issue.

Comment: Chrome gives me this: Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.7bks.com

Comment: In a command window? dig www.google.com is an unrecognized command... Same as traceroute.. What am I missing (windows/PC over here)

Comment: I get this: C:\Users\Tom>ping www.google.com

Pinging www.l.google.com [72.14.204.103] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 72.14.204.103:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
Which is strange since I can access Google in Chrome just fine...

Comment: That's weird, do you know how to change your dns server?